# Convert or Extract String to Address type in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, street-address

i am trying to convert a String to an address format. The goal would be to have a string like

"12233 Abbb street, Los Angeles, CA 92666" to a

```
address: 12233 Abbb street
address2:
city: Los Angeles
state: CA
zip: 92666
```

Any idea how, I can't find a lib to do it

Comment: If they all are seperated by a `,` you can just use `split` function of `string`, and map accordingly.

Comment: If you're trying to build a universal solution. You can use a workaround . use Geo coder to get LatLng and then reverse geocode the LatLng to get the specific details of the location

Answer (score -1):

No other libraries are needed to implement it, just use string separation.

Of course, this solution is not the best solution. What you need to fundamentally solve the problem of data format. Simply using strings is not a very good method. What you need more is Json or other string format to solve the problem.

Below is my conversion code:

```kotlin
data class Entity(
     val address: String = "",
     val address2: String = "",
     val city: String = "",
     val state: String = "",
     val zip: Int = 0
)

fun String.convertToEntity(): Entity {
     val array = split(",")
     if (array.size <3) return Entity()
     return Entity(
         address = array.firstOrNull() ?: "",
         city = array[1],
         state = array.lastOrNull()?.split(" ")?.firstOrNull {it.isNotEmpty()} ?: "",
         zip = array.lastOrNull()?.split(" ")?.lastOrNull {it.isNotEmpty() }?.toIntOrNull() ?: 0
     )
}
```

Believe me, a plain String cannot solve your problem. Once there is any error in the data returned to you by the backend, or you have typed more spaces when filling in the interface. There will be a problem with the above code.

**update**

As Gabe Sechan said, libraries are needed. I don't have any suggestions for similar libraries. The answers above are just for questions. If anyone finds a similar library, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Saying no other libraries are needed is misleading at the very least.  There isn't one universal address format.  There's hundreds.  If he needs to write anything that is remotely resembling production he's going to need a library or he's going to be fixing bugs for years.  And saying "You need JSON" is getting at that point, but reality is when people type in their address its not going to be as a JSON blob.  You sometimes need to parse a string address.

Comment: Can you provide me with a similar library?

Comment: I can't provide a recommendation, its been too many years since I've worked with one.  But a quick google search find a few open source solutions, and I know there's paid ones as well.

Comment: It’s misleading about "there is no similar library’", I will revise my answer. Thank you very much for your time and energy